# IntelliJ IDEA: library available on src\test\java but not on src\main\java

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I use pom.xml on my project and found the issue with project library.
Library available on src\test\java but not on src\main\java

[image]

How to make library available for both main and test?

Here is snippet from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your pom.xml to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

This problem caused due to you set your dependency could only seen in test scope. (`scope` in `dependency`)

See also: [Maven Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Comment: You don't need the scope at all if you're just having it as a normal dependency.

Comment: Yes...But I always set it to `compile`